# Concatenate Audio Files with pause in between each audio clip

Tags: audio, audacity

I need to concatenate two or more audio clips into a single track, with a pause in ms between in each clip. This is for a voice over composed of multiple clips.

I want to do this as a batch process, rather than manually adding clips and adding a pause in between each one using Audacity/Audition etc.

Is there a way of doing this via cmd or using a script for an ideally free application like Audacity?

Comment: ffmpeg is your friend ... there are tons of questions/answers on this forum on `ffmpeg` ... there is a terminal command line binary which you can call from a script using bash or similar shell or if you need very heavy lifting ffmpeg publishes a library you can call from say c or c++ or python or ...

Comment: If you are using Java, the coding is not terribly difficult, and I'm willing to help by providing an outline of the steps with some explanation for each. I understand the desire to just get it done with a library, though, if one exists.